# ORACLE use custom tableObject into a function

Tags: oracle

I want insert a cursor into my custom `tableObject`, but it is not always found.

My RECORD:

```
create or replace type "RECORDRANKING" as object
(

  -- Attributes
  COL1 NUMBER,
  COL2 VARCHAR(50),
  COL3 NUMBER

  -- Member functions and procedures
 -- member procedure <ProcedureName>(<Parameter> <Datatype>)
)
```

This is object table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TBRANKING" AS TABLE OF RECORDRANKING;
```

Now I go into creating a function (into a package):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKLBOTTONI as
FUNCTION testlb
( 
p_gapup IN NUMBER, 
p_gadown IN NUMBER
)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
cursor_ranking SYS_REFCURSOR;
position NUMBER ;
gap_ranking TBRANKING;
gaprecord RECORDRANKING;
upgap NUMBER;
downgap NUMBER;
     BEGIN
      select * into cursor_ranking from(
        select pkranking.getRanking(  100 ) from dual); 

LOOP  
FETCH cursor_ranking INTO gap_ranking;
EXIT WHEN cursor_ranking%NOTFOUND;
   INSERT INTO gap_ranking       (COL1,COL2,COL3)
   VALUES 
   (cursor_ranking.C1,
   cursor_ranking.C2,
   cursor_ranking.C3);
 END LOOP;
return gap_ranking; 
END;


END PKLBOTTONI;
```

I always get:

```
Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY PKLBOTTONI

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Line: 32
Text: INSERT INTO gap_ranking
```

Comment: how to can create it?

Comment: what version of oracle?

Comment: There's other issues there. Does your function need to return SYS_REFCURSOR or TBRANKING? The code is trying to return "gap_ranking" but "gap_ranking" is _not_ of type SYS_REFCURSOR.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you're both fetching into "gap_ranking" and then trying to "insert into" it again. Insert into a collection is not a valid syntax. Fetch is ok, either in a loop or using bulk collect to fetch multiple records at once.

From your excerpt it doesn't look like you have a physical database table, so the way to do it in PL/SQL would be something like below.

For more help using collections you can check Oracle docs below too:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    gap_ranking tbranking := tbranking(null); -- initialize
  3  begin
  4    gap_ranking.delete; -- clear empty record
  5    for cur in
  6      (select level as i from dual connect by level <= 5)
  7    loop
  8      -- insert empty
  9      gap_ranking.extend;
 10      -- attribute values
 11      gap_ranking(gap_ranking.last) := recordranking(1000 + cur.i, 'TEST' || cur.i, 10 + cur.i);
 12    end loop;
 13    -- loop to print - just to illustrate
 14    for j in gap_ranking.first .. gap_ranking.last
 15    loop
 16      dbms_output.put_line(gap_ranking(j).col1 || ',' ||
 17                           gap_ranking(j).col2 || ',' ||
 18                           gap_ranking(j).col3);
 19  
 20    end loop;
 21    -- same as...
 22    for j in 1 .. gap_ranking.count
 23    loop
 24      dbms_output.put_line(gap_ranking(j).col1 || ',' ||
 25                           gap_ranking(j).col2 || ',' ||
 26                           gap_ranking(j).col3);
 27  
 28    end loop;
 29  end;
 30  /
1001,TEST1,11
1002,TEST2,12
1003,TEST3,13
1004,TEST4,14
1005,TEST5,15
1001,TEST1,11
1002,TEST2,12
1003,TEST3,13
1004,TEST4,14
1005,TEST5,15
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL>
```

Comment: but in function i can write (declare???) i have write...package, function..sorry but it's important for me write all

Comment: please use my example function

Comment: That was a sample so you get the feel of it. It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish with the insert. Why are you using ref cursors when you're actually trying to insert their data _values_?

Comment: it's too much complex, your example for me

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'd need more information to use your function. Is there any way you could clarify what your function is expected to Return?

Comment: the function return a (SYS_REFCURSOR |RECORDSET). I want insert my cursor result (select pkranking.getRanking() from dual);) into temp table (gap_ranking). **gap_ranking** is a table object. After will want do a select (select * from gap_ranking where a=1)